# code for loadig re-captcha plugin in joomla 2.5

Tags: plugins, joomla2.5, captcha

I want to add default re-captcha plugin to my joomla website.
I write the following code:

```
//php code
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','dynamic_recaptcha_1');

//html code
 <div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>
```

But nothing is displayed!! I tried to find a lot but couldnt get a solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thn.

Comment: In which context is that code running?

Comment: I have a form in my custom component. I put the php code in view.html.php and the html code at the place I want to display captcha , in default.php.

Comment: Is it so that the plugin works only with jform?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the captcha plugin in extensions->plugins?
You will also have to fill in the private and public keys in the plugin.

Comment: Yes I have enabled the plugin and enetered the keys also

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding client-side validation to your form.

http://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation

e.g.

```
JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidation');

<form class="form-validate"> ... </form>

<field name="email" type="text" class="required validate-email" size="30" />

//For radios make sure the class is applied to the options: 

<field name="ThisorThat" type="radio" label="Please say if it was full-time or the part-time equivalent?" >
 <option value="This" class="required">This</option>
 <option value="That" class="required">That</option>
</field>
```

Then as long as you have ReCaptcha selected as your default Captcha in your Global config it should show up.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thnx, this time its loading the plugin, but still captcha is'nt showing up... I tried to keep public key empty and it showed error, so it is loading the plugin, but captcha doesnt appear!

Comment: Did you make sure to put both your public and private key into the plugin setting from the administrator section?

Comment: I wonder if you have css getting applied to it that you are not aware of... I would suggest doing some inspect element digging to see why the captcha image is not showing up.

Answer (score -1):

Joomla often uses MooTools library.

Try to insert again

```
<script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/plugins/captcha/idcaptcha/idcaptcha.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

before

```
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>
```